# Limitations of Polymorphism in statically typed languages

Tags: java, design, c++, javascript, polymorphism

I program mostly in statically typed languages, like C++ and Java.  A common strategy employed in languages like these to handle dealing with collections of objects which are *related*, but which need to employ specific behaviors, is to use polymorphism and inheritance hierarchies.  But Polymorphism only works when the Base class has a method (virtual function) which can then be overridden by every Derived class.  But there are often cases where a Derived class needs to have a method, and it doesn't make sense to place a method of the same name in the Base class, because it is very specific to the Derived class.

Let me give a concrete example that many of us can probably relate to: the HTML DOM.

Javascript programmers are quite used to doing things like iterating over collections of DOM nodes.  They take for granted the dynamically-typed nature of Javascript when they do something like:

```
node = document.getElementById("foo");
for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) 
    doSomething(node.childNodes[i]);
```

Something like this would be very messy to do in a statically typed language like Java, because inheritance-based polymorphism doesn't lend itself well to situations where Derived classes have methods which don't exist in the Base class.  For example, when iterating over the above HTML Nodes, we might find a DIV node, which has certain methods, and a Text node, which has certain different methods, and a TABLE node, which has its own unique methods - and it wouldn't make much sense for ALL of these various methods to exist in a common Base class "Node", because they are highly specific to each Derived type.  (e.g. a DIV node has no need of a "cells" method, but a TABLE node does.)

So, in a statically typed language, you'd be forced to fall back on something like Type Enums and a lot of messy down-casting to check what type of Node you have.  So basically you end up with messy code like:

```
Node node = document.getElementById("foo");
for (int i = 0; i < node.childNodes().length(); ++i) 
{
   Node n = node.childNodes().elementAt(i);
   if (n.type() == Node.DIV_NODE) doSomethingWithDiv(((DivNode)(n)));
   else if (n.type() == Node.TABLE_NODE) doSomethingWithTable(((TableNode)(n)));
   /* etc... */
}
```

This is similar to what C programmers do, and it's seemingly the sort of thing virtual functions were designed to *avoid*.  And yet, when you're faced with a situation where there are various different methods in a Derived class for which it doesn't make any sense to place in a common base class, you have no recourse but to resort to something like Type Enums.

So, how is this problem usually addressed in statically-typed languages?  Is there a better design pattern than Type Enums?

Comment: You can avoid the messy code by using a common virtual method (call it, say, processNode()) and putting the appropriate implementation for each subclass. The fact that the method is virtual ensures that the correct implementation is chosen based on the type of the object on which it is invoked. In the body of the method you put your doSomethingWithDiv(), doSomethingWithTable(), etc, and you do not need any extra enum juggling. Your call would look like  node.childNodes().elementAt(i).processNode() and all the type-specific code would be in the implementation of processNode().

Comment: If you need to do completely different things (that is, differently "named" actions) for different types, then your method/function is not polymorphic. This isn't a flaw of static typing or polymorphism, but a problem with your design. Also, your example isn't very good: you can very well `doSomething` with polymorphism, for different Node types!

Comment: If you really need different behavior in doSomething depending on the specific class, how would the javascript example make sense?

Whereas doSomethingWithTable and doSomethingWithDiv can obviously have different behaviour, in the javascript example, you would most likely have to make the checks somehow also.

Obviously, a better approach is to include doSomething (or it's functionality) inside the node base class and override for each node - as someone else also pointed out.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't a limitation in statically typed languages, there exists a solution to this problem which is to declare a common Interface between the various classes for the operations that you care about.  This allows you to do whatever you need to do, while still being type safe.

Comment: That is known as a fat interface, and it’s an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Konrad I disagree: a fat interface means you're trying to incorporate every single common operation in a single interface, which is indeed an anti-pattern. However, abstracting a _simple_, common interface for a set of types (and for the point of view of a given operation) is the basis of polymorphism, whether this interface is explicit, as in Java, or implicit, as in duck typing.

Comment: @Andres The whole point of the example was that there isn’t necessarily a logical common interface between these types which has the required methods. The interface between the classes in OP’s example would be relatively generic, and certainly doesn’t provide table node-specific (say) methods.

Comment: @Konrad Agreed, but that is a problem with the conceptual algorithm, and somewhat unrelated to duck typing vs static typing. If the OP's algorithm wants to "do something" with whatever stuff there is in a doc, the best he can do with interfaces is DocElementAboutWhichSomethingCanBeDone ;) With duck typing he is merely turning a blind eye on the _conceptual mess_ of his algorithm, which isn't a good thing either. I do agree pattern matching, as you suggested in your answer, is a more elegant (and statically typed!) solution.

Comment: @Konrad To be less verbose: I agree with this answer in that this isn't a "limitation of statically typed languages". If you can't easily reason about your algorithm, that's a symptom of a deeper flaw, I think. Duck typing in this case is simply not even attempting to reason.

Comment: And what if those classes are closed?  Do you then write an adapter for every one?

Comment: @kevincline: That would be a limitation on particular languages -- you don't necessarily have to "apply" an interface to a class. It's possible to have the compiler verify the interface (i.e. matching properties and signatures), without requiring the class to make the declaration that it supports the interface. This gives type safety, without requiring that the writer of the class to declare that it supports the interface.

Comment: @Konrad: The idea that someone wants to store, iterate over, and call the same method on a bunch of objects without them having a logical common interface seems weird to me, too. If they have nothing in common, how come they are bunched together in some container and support the same operation? (See also [my answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/160770/1512).)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: unless your particular language limits you to a single interface (and if there is such a language, I don't want to know about it except to avoid it), this is most definitely not a "fat" interface.

Comment: @jmoreno Maybe we misunderstand each other – if your language supports classes implementing multiple interfaces (and as you’ve said, all do) then why would you use *one common* interface rather than several separate ones? It’s that one common interface which is referred to as “fat interface”, [pretty much by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_bloat). And, like I mentioned in a previous comment, the whole point of OP’s example is that the classes *don’t* share a logical common interface for many of the operations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You use a common interface for a particular algorithm.  In the OP's example that would be DoSomething, given that he had only one operation.  So even if it was completely crazy and the operations had no logical connection, say DoSomethingTable setup tables, DoSomethingDiv looked for the word pink somewhere on the page and made it's background color red, you could still have a common interface DoSomething, just as in his javascript example.  If anything what I am trying to describe could lead to too many interfaces, but realistically I wouldn't expect that to happen.

Comment: @jmoreno Absolutely agreed. I understood the question to include the operations `childNodes`, `getElementsById` etc. in the consideration. – Even then this would probably be okay.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Fat interfaces would often be a good thing if interfaces could that an implementations missing particular members should be supplied with auto-generated wrappers that call designated static members.  `IEnumerable<T>` would IMHO be better if it were a more general readable-collection interface, with members that chained to static members that behave much like the extension methods in `Enumerable<T>`.  If code wants the last item in a 1,000,000-item linked list, asking the list for its last item (time O(1)) would be much more efficient than iterating through it (O(N)), but...

Comment: ...such a thing is only possible if there's a standard way of asking something for its last item.  Making the readable-collection interface fat would not only allow one `ReadonlyCollection` wrapper could handle all variations, but it would also allow code that receives a collection and wants to return a read-only wrapper to return a wrapper that exposes all of the useful modes of reading the received collection supports.  I know of no way to achieve nearly as nice a result without using a fat interface.  Too bad MS hasn't yet provided a way to eliminate boilerplate on implementations.

Comment: @supercat I agree that for such purposes a fat interface (or better, a mixin) would be entirely appropriate. But consider OP’s example, where something like this wouldn’t work, and many methods would by default have to throw some kind of `NotImplementedException`. This is actually a thing in some .NET libraries.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: There are a few cases where it makes sense to have a heterogeneous collection and invoke on every item of certain types methods which could not be sensibly included in other types of items.  In many such cases, however, if one might reasonably expect that code holding a collection of `IWidget` might want all items that can "Fnorble" to do so, that would suggest that `CanFnorble` and `FnorbleIfPossible` should be at least considered as candidates for inclusion in `IWidget`, if one has a language/framework that makes fat interfaces convenient to work with.

Comment: @supercat I’d argue that *the correct* (I’m refraining from saying “the *only* correct”, but I’m hinting at it) way of doing this is via a tagged union and a visitor, as explained in my own answer. Unfortunately most modern mainstream languages have limited syntactic support for this.

Answer (score 6):

Best fit would probably be [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

And if you need to do things like this, then you should re-think your object model, because having behavior, that works only on specific type should be part of that type.

Answer (score 4):

This is what **interfaces** are for. You shouldn't be using a base class for this. Base classes signal a relationship of the `A is a B` kind; interfaces say `A can do X`.

Using the traditional animal example: a `Bee` is an `Insect`, which is an `Animal`. A `Sparrow` is a `Bird`, which is also an `Animal`. Both bees and sparrows can fly, but not all animals can fly, and what's worse, not even all insects nor birds can fly. So where does the `fly()` method go? `Animal`? Or should we restructure our class hierarchy so that `Bee` and `Sparrow` have a common ancestor? But if we do that, we cannot have a common ancestor for `Penguin` and `Sparrow` that provides a beak without either making penguins fly or equipping bees with beaks (draw the class hierarchies out on paper if you don't get it).

The solution is to have a `FlyingAnimal` interface, which provides the signature for `fly()`; whenever you need a collection of flying animals, declare it as `Collection<FlyingAnimal>`.

Using interface inheritance, you can group interfaces into 'super-interfaces', e.g., you can have an `FlyingAndWalkingAnimal` which inherits `fly()` from `FlyingAnimal` and `walk()` from `WalkingAnimal`.

Answer (score 4):

To me it seems your problem is either a flaw in your understanding or a flaw in your design. Or both. `:)`

What your example attempts do (and does in JS) is to ***execute a method with the same name on each of a bunch of objects of unrelated types***. That's one of those hacks you do when you knocking up a quick throw-away tool in some scripting language, and it has its place there.

But static languages are statically typed so that ***the compiler can catch simple errors*** like calling a non-existent method at compile time. When you are doing development in such a language, the assumption naturally is that you mean business, that your program is to be run at some customers, and that you want to weed out as many bugs as possible as early as possible.

One of the things a statically language requires in order to be able to hold your hand is that you ***express it in your design*** if a group of types support the same operation. You do this by deriving them from the same base class or interface, which ***declares that this operation is available in all derived classes***. If you don't do this, your code will have to invent numerous hacks in order to achieve the same goal. (A wise man once said that a switch over types — which is what your `if(n.type() == Node.SOME_TYPE) ... else if(n.type() == Node.SOME_OTHER_TYPE) ...` really amounts to — is just unreasonable fear of virtual function.)

So: *If* those types support the same operation, and *if* you want to execute that operation on objects of any of those types without really caring which concrete type they're of, then you need to declare those operations available in some ***common base class or interface***. (For the corner case that you have only a relatively small number of types, but a number of unrelated operations, which would unreasonably fatten a base class' interface, there's idioms like the Visitor Pattern which employ multiple dispatch to solve that problem.)

Answer (score 3):

That you need this at all is a failure in your design. Subtypes exist to act as a refinement of your base type. If you need specific behaviors, then work with the specific type.

The better pattern is to let the collection supply the collection of specific types you need (ala CSS/jquery selectors).

Comment: I think you have misunderstood his concrete example which showcases a very decidedly non-failed design which *does* require this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There's always type-checking either at compile-time or at run-time you just don't call it so. For example, the JavaScript fragment looks very impressive, but it hides the details about doSomething. Yes, it can accept any object and any object can have very specific set of methods, but this function should access methods and properties so assumes the methods it needs are there, otherwise it will give you run-time error. So you either previously filter objects for passing to be safe for doSomething or it will do this inside. The statically typed languages have luxury (or burden, depending on the POV) to do much of this work at compile-time leaving part to run-time with a little help of RTTI

Answer (score 1):

All statically typed languages have a built-in method which is quite equivalent, such as `instanceof` or `dynamic_cast`. DOM elements do have some shared interfaces which you could put in a base class. However, there are statically typed tools which are not inheritance- for example, `boost::variant` and `boost::any` which can provide dynamic typing between elements which are not related by inheritance.

Comment: Not all languages have classes...so no instanceof

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of handling this in statically typed languages. Probably the most elegant is pattern matching. Here’s Haskell:

```
doSomething (DivNode n)     = does something with a div node
doSomething (TableNode n)   = does something with a table node
doSomething _               = do nothing
```

The same, or similar, mechanisms exist in other statically typed languages (F#, Scala as far as I know). In C++, the same can be emulated (albeit more verbosely) with the Boost.Variant and the static visitor:

```
struct visit_node : static_visitor<void> {
    void operator ()(DivNode const& n) {
        // Do something with a div node.
    }

    void operator ()(TableNode const& n) {
        // Do something with a table node.
    }

    template <typename T>
    void operator ()(T const& n) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

(It’s worth noting that this looks like compile-time overload resolution but thanks to the magic of Boost.Variant, this will work at runtime, and be completely type safe.)

More generally, a [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can be used to implement it, but they are even more verbose than Boost’s [`static_visitor` helper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/static_visitor.html) and (which essentially abstracts away the cruft) which makes them very unresponsive to changes in the class hierarchy.

And yes, you can obviously hard-code the dispatch via dynamic casts as some other answers have shown. That’s easily the worst possible solution, though. Like the above methods, it hard-codes the type hierarchy, but it does so in a particularly verbose way.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use reflection to determine if an object has a particular method on it.  But it's better to collect your interface methods into an interface, and if you need to see if an object provides that interface, it's just a cast away.

Similarly, while C++ does not provide reflection, it does provide RTTI and `dynamic_cast` (or, better yet, you're using `shared_ptr` and `dynamic_ptr_cast`) which you can use to query a C++ object for an interface (which is a pattern expressed via multiple inheritance, rather than a specific language feature).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you have different problem in statically typed languages versus dynamically typed ones. Because the only difference in dynamically typed language is that you don't have to declare the interface and that an error is only detected at runtime.

However in both cases you have to either:

- Check the actual type of the instance and only call the method you know it has. The only difference is that statically typed language will need a cast.
- Have all the methods in all the types, even the ones where they don't make sense.
- Use a [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which is quite simple in statically typed languages, while it requires introspection in most dynamic ones.

There is a handful of languages that have dynamic multiple dispatch, but IIRC there are both dynamic and static ones that do (and none widely used).

Answer (score 0):

Your example begs the question: How do you KNOW that you are iterating over a set of DOMs?  How do you know something else didn't sneak in there?  How do you know the new hire from PoliticallyCorrectUniversity read the documentation closely enough, and didn't call your routine with the wrong list of stuff?

You want the compiler to catch these things for you.  That's what strong typing and static typing are all about.  (Recall the ALGOL committee's reply to Wirth's proposal for default type rules for ALGOL.)

You can tell the compiler what you are doing in one of two ways: put a virtual method in the base class (or in an interface), with an error barf for the default case that everyone EXCEPT the privileged derived class will inherit, or, as you said, "fall back on something like Type Enums and a lot of messy down-casting to check what type of Node you have".

Answer (score 0):

Here's some rules of using inheritance:

1. Separate your code to two parts: interface and implementation
2. interface must publish *all* data via the interface
3. implementation can implement *only* the functions available in the interface. No other implementation is allowed.
4. constructor parameters of derived class are part of the "interface" of an object -- the interface is divided to two parts: common base class, and constructor parameters of derived class
5. All *specific* behaviour is handled via constructor parameters

Answer (score -1):

First, if you want something similar to what you'd have written in javascript, the if statements would probably go in the body of the doSomething method rather than outside. It's not cleaner, just closer to your javascript example.

That being said, you can do the exact same thing in a static language using method Overloading. Actually, it's even better : you'd remove all the if statements alltogether!

Let's say both `DivNode` and `TableNode` inherit from a `Node` type.

Then, if ou write the 3 following functions, you don't need any for loop or casting :

```
private void doSomething(Node node) {
   throw new RuntimeException ("This method should never be called !");
}

private void doSomething (DivNode divNode) {
   // function body
}

private void doSomething (TableNode tableNode) {
   // function body
}
```

Comment: Actually, overload resolution is done at compile time in Java, so if he is accepting instances of the parent class the compiler can't route the methods dynamically.